# How do I get Series[] as a functional, rather than as an expression (i.e. to avoid the dummy variable)?

Tags: functions, function-construction, series-expansion

How can I write an equivalent to `Series` that doesn't require a dummy variable?

Note that the series should be constructed *before* the evaluation point is supplied, not after.

Also, I'd rather avoid using `Unique[]` if possible (so that multiple return the same thing), and I want to avoid scope leaks as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Updated] It does not *quite* seem to be possible to avoid generating new variable names, since there is always a need to avoid potential conflicts with the body of each function.

However, it is possible to avoid calling `Unique`:

```
FSeries[f_, xo__] := Module[{t},
   With[{args = 
      Symbol /@ 
       Array[SymbolName[t] <> "$" <> ToString[#1] &, Length[{xo}]]},
    Function[Evaluate[args], 
     Evaluate[
      Apply[Series, 
       Prepend[MapThread[Prepend[#1, #2] &, {{xo}, args}], 
        Apply[f, args]]]]]]];
```

Now if you say:

```
FSeries[Exp, {1, 3}]
```

you get back the 3rd-degree Taylor series of `Exp` around `1`, which you can then call `Normal` on to turn it into a regular series without the `O[]` portion.

Comment: This seems to fail: `FSeries[Exp[#1 + #2] &, {a, 1}, {b, 1}][1, 2]`

Comment: @MichaelE2: Fail in what way? Did you call `Normal` on the output of `FSeries`?

Comment: Actually `Unique` get called by `Module`...

Comment: @unlikely: Whoops. Well this is the best answer I've been able to find, let me know if you find something better.

Comment: @Mehrdad Maybe you like my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Why *something like* this is not enough?

```
FSeries[f_, xo__] := 
 With[{fn = Series[f[#], {#, Sequence @@ xo}]}, fn &]
FSeries[Exp, {1, 3}]
```

> SeriesData[#, 1, {E, E, Rational[1, 2] E, Rational[1, 6] E}, 0, 4, 1] 
>    &

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**[EDIT]** Or this?

```
FSeries[f_, xo__] :=
 With[{args = Slot /@ Range@Length@{xo}},
  With[{fn = Normal@Series[f @@ args, Sequence @@ MapThread[Prepend, {{xo}, args}]]},
    fn &]
  ]

FSeries[Exp, {1, 3}]
FSeries[Exp[#1 + #2] &, {a, 1}, {b, 1}]
```

As pointed by @MichealE2, the `Normal` is necessary to evaluate the result for numerical values in the multivariate case, but you loose the `O` also for symbolic arguments. So a possible problem is if you want to handle (how?) numerical and non-numerical arguments in multivariate.

**[EDIT 2]** Maybe you like this. If you use formal symbols in the intended way use and you don't normally define functions with 53 arguments or more, this version satisfy your requirements.

```
FSeries[f_, xo__] :=
 With[{args = Symbol /@ Take[CharacterRange["\[FormalA]", "\[FormalCapitalZ]"], Length@{xo}]},
  With[{fn = Series[f @@ args, Sequence @@ MapThread[Prepend, {{xo}, args}]]},
   Function @@ {args, fn}
   ]
  ]


FSeries[Exp, {1, 3}]
FSeries[Exp[#1 + #2] &, {a, 1}, {b, 1}]
(Normal@FSeries[Exp[#1 + #2] &, {a, 1}, {b, 1}])[1, 2]
FSeries[Function[t, Exp[#1]], {0, 2}]
```

> ```
> Function[{\[FormalA]}, SeriesData[\[FormalA], 1, {E, E, Rational[1, 2] E, Rational[1, 6] E}, 0, 4, 1]]
> Function[{\[FormalA], \[FormalB]}, SeriesData[\[FormalA], a, {
> SeriesData[\[FormalB], b, {E^(a + b), E^(a + b)}, 0, 2, 1], 
> SeriesData[\[FormalB], b, {E^(a + b), E^(a + b)}, 0, 2, 1]}, 0, 2, 1]]
> E^(a + b) + (2 - b) E^(a + b) + (1 - a) (E^(a + b) + (2 - b) E^(a + b))
> Function[{\[FormalA]}, E^#1]
> ```

Comment: Because it fails on something like `FSeries[Exp[#1 + #2] &, {a, 1}, {b, 1}]`.

Comment: @Mehrdad "something like"... see my edit... I miss the point of `Inactive` for example...

Comment: It was meant to prevent some bugs that (I just now realized) it apparently didn't prevent... and which yours apparently also suffers from: try `FSeries[Function[t, Exp[#1]], {0, 2}]` and notice that `#1` gets substituted when it shouldn't.

Comment: @Mehrdad I miss the use-case of this syntax, but, if you want, I think changing `Slot` with `Inactive[Slot]` and appending an `//Activate` at the end of my version can work. I'm not sure because I don't know what you want to get.

Comment: Oh, I want it to give the same exact result as `Series[Function[t, Exp[#1]][t], {t, 0, 2}]`, i.e. `Series[Exp[#1], {t, 0, 2}]`. (I realize it looks useless, but I still want it to be correct since I don't want to track down a bug because of it later.) I'm fairly sure the solution can't be so simple -- otherwise you might `Activate` things that the user didn't intend to. Are you sure that would work?

Comment: @Mehrdad the problem is that `Series[Exp[#1], {t, 0, 2}]` is a series of a constant, so it's the *constant* `Exp[#1]`. How do you plan to represent this constant in a pure fuction without named arguments? Or do you want to returns `Function[t, Exp[#1]]`?

Comment: I have no insistence that we avoid named arguments. I just don't want there to be any scope leakage or use of `Unique[]`. If you can do it with named arguments (in fact that's what I'm trying right now) that's fine.

Comment: @Mehrdad sorry, I'll leave to you this exercise, it's late night here...

Comment: @Mehrdad I think you can't do a very robust version and avoid `Unique` or similar construct as of your question. If you are defining you `FSeries` inside a package, you can use a private symbol, so you can always return the same (set of) symbols for every call, as of your requirements. If nothing is good, I think you can't get the level of robustness you are searching.

Comment: Yeah I realized the same thing, see the edit I made to my own answer.